# How to upload a new file to deployment manager via API

Tags: jelastic

Looking at jelastic's api [documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/) but I can't figure out how to upload a file to our deployment manager via API, or fetch those URLs via Jelastic api. Is there a way to do that?

The goal here is to upload a file via API, retrieve that URL and then use the DeployArchive endpoint to upload it to a specific context.

If there's not a way of uploading a file to the deployment manager is there an alternative way of deploying a zip/war to a specific context completely via API?

Comment: Where do you build zip/war? From which place do you want to upload?

Comment: @Ruslan I build it in a remote machine that is not exposed online, I want to upload a file from that remote computer but I do NOT want to make that file publicly available on the internet.

Comment: you can install ownCloud and upload / download from that env https://github.com/jelastic-jps/owncloud. Or install FTP addon https://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support and use ftp:// links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to upload files via API to the deployment manager.
To deploy the application to the specific context, you can use following API request:

```
https://[hoster-api-host]/1.0/environment/control/rest/deployapp?envname=[string]&session=[string]&fileurl=[string]&filename=[string]&context=[string]
```

where:

**envname** - the name of the environment, **session** - your session, **fileurl** - link to file, **filename** - name of the archive file, **context** - given context. If context is not defined then application will be deployed to the ROOT context

More information on this API request can be found in our API [documentation](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/) Environment -> Control -> DeployApp

Comment: is there any level of security we can add to the fileurl? Like basic auth or our deployment file has to be publicly available in the internet?

Comment: common rules should work ftp://username:password@hostname/file.war or https://username:password@hostname/file.war